# The backend with a language and frontend with another language

Tags: magento, internationalization, e-commerce

I have my site with Magento, and I want to keep management (backend) in the German language, and in my frontend that language must be Spanish.

Can I do that? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The locale for the frontend is set at

```
System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale Options
```

While the locale for the backend can be changed from the *Interface Locale* drop down at the bottom of every admin console page.